# Is the total handles limit 10000, or 20000?

Tags: winforms, gdi

Is the oft-quoted handles limit of 10,000 for both GDI and users objects, or for each?

In other words, is the limit 10,000, or 20,000?

I've inherited a large application that creates a large number of Windows forms, with a large number of controls on each form, and I'm hitting the handles limit (I think), with an OutOfMemoryException. Just need to know what the actual limit is in total, to better understand why I'm getting this.

Comment: This has nothing to do with .NET, and there is no limit on .NET handles. GDI is *used* by .NET, but it isn't *part of* .NET. In any case, this is easily found on MSDN. And, of course... why do you care? The point of SO is to solve problems, not ansver trivia questions. If you have a real problem with your code that you think has something to do with GDI handles, *ask that question*.

Comment: Ok so how do I find this out on MSDN? I've been looking for 30 mins and I've found nothing so far.

Comment: Handle quota are an operating system setting, nothing to do with .NET.  Yes, 10,000 is the default for each, far beyond what is reasonable.  The quota exists to prevent one process from taking its unfair share of the desktop heap, a resource that needs to be shared by all processes that run on that desktop.

Comment: Are you getting an error? A visual glitch? Why do you think you've hit the handle limit? Have you checked with Process Explorer?

Comment: @Hans - thanks, that's all I needed to know.

Comment: @Luaan - I'm monitoring the number of GDI objects and User objects allocated as my program runs, and at some point, I get an OutOfMemory exception, but it's hard to determine exactly where.

Comment: Not sure why this is considered a bad question.

Comment: So you see the number of GDI objects approach 10k when the exception is thrown? Getting `OutOfMemoryException` from GDI is tricky, because it sadly maps to many common errors - like "this image format is incorrect/unknown". It's hard to see how you could hit the limit in a reasonable application, even if you preload all your forms at once (yeah, I inherited one such app as well... Delphi coders die hard :D). Could it be (if it is in fact a problem with handles) that some resources aren't disposed of properly?

Comment: As for the question itself, it's getting better over time. Just rewrite it to be about your *actual observed problem*, and you'll be fine. Try adding as much relevant information as possible, and mention the possible handle issue more neutrally (e.g. "I'm monitoring the handle count, and just before the exception happens, it's usually over 9000. Could this be the problem? What can I do to solve this?"). Most of the down votes from your original question will stay of course - just try not to ask encyclopaedic questions the next time :) Your *actual* problem is a fine question for SO IMO.

Comment: No, we're not approaching 10k on either GDI or user handles, but a user got an OutOfMemory exception with counts that were close to 10000 in total, hence the question. Now I know it's actually 20000, the exception must be for some other reason (I have hit the limit just on User objects before when loading multiple panels, and got that exception). I appreciate though that there's other reasons we might be getting the exception.

Comment: @Luaan ok thanks for the advice.